# How do I say in French 'I can't wait to see them!' ?

Tags: grammaire, formulation-idiomatique

I am writing about visiting Niagara Falls in the future and I would like to know how to say 'I can't wait to see them!' (I'm not sure if it would be referred to as 'them' or 'it' either)

Comment: http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/can't%20wait

Answer (score 3):

> 1. J'ai (vraiment) hâte d'aller voir les chutes du Niagara.
> 2. Je meurs d'envie d'aller voir les chutes du Niagara.
> 3. Il me tarde d'aller voir les chutes du Niagara.
> 4. Vivement que j'aille voir les chutes du Niagara.
> 5. Je brûle (d'impatience) d'aller voir les chutes du Niagara.

Considering that "falls" is expressed as "les chutes" in the plural:

> 1+. J'ai (vraiment) hâte d'aller les voir.

Comment: Would "Je ne peux pas attendre de les voir" be also correct?

Comment: @MarcoRubenAbuyuanLlanes this litteral translation makes little sense in French.

Comment: Oh, okay thanks! So you have to use "avoir hâte de"? For this all the time?

Comment: Is this because saying "ne pouvoir pas" is basically "I am unable to wait to see them"?

Comment: "ne pas pouvoir" is literally "not being able to". In English the meaning is weakened in this very expression, but it is not in French. Basically You would mean "There is some material constraint that makes me unable to wait to see them", like if you were waiting for the falls to come but your plane was departing and you had to leave now. Yes, that makes no sense.