# How to express “I’m looking forward to vacation”?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

How to say “I'm looking forward to summer vacation” in French? I want to tell my French friend that I’ve learned so much for university and now I’m looking forward to vacation.

Answer (score 6):

- "J'ai hâte d'être en vacances"

or

- "Je suis impatient d'être en vacances"

or their informal equivalent:

- "Vivement les vacances!"

I personally would not specify "Summer" in the french translation

Comment: the last one is clearly the most commonly used

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

> Ah, comme j'ai hâte d'être en vacances !
>
> Les grandes vacances me tardent ! == *Vacation cannot come/arrive soon enough!*
>
> Des vacances relaxantes, voilà ce qu'il me faut !

---

Not the same phrasing, but essentially the same idea:

[How do I say in French 'I can't wait to see them!' ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19529/how-do-i-say-in-french-i-cant-wait-to-see-them)

Comment: Nobody would speak your second sentence in real life. (And in your third sentence you introduce the extra meaning of "relaxing" that is absent from OP's sentence – maybe OP's idea of a vacation is hiking through Siberia.)

Comment: *Les grandes vacances me tardent* is unlikely to be heard but "nobody would say it" is exaggerated ( http://gaby.cw.cowblog.fr/les-grandes-vacances-me-tardent-3105099.html , https://twitter.com/enzotaistoi/status/739172221692870656, ...) Rearranging the sentence would make it more common : ***Il me tarde d'être en vacances***.

Answer (score 1):

"Vivement les vacances!" is clearly the most common.
If you really want to precise which vacation you mean, I would say that "Vivement les grandes vacances!" is adequate, as the summer holidays are the longest of the year.